# geoserver openlayer and googlemap offset

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, geoserver

in my application I am using a googlemap as baselayer and geoserver as wms server for adding several layers to the googlemap, at the first load there is an offset between the layers and the googlemap, it disappears if I switch-on and off some developing tool in a browser, like firebug on firefox and development tools in chrome, I activated the sphericalmercator on the baseLayer, but still there is the offset, my code is visible at pastebin.com/rn9xQbke, I need someone more experienced to point me on the right direction

Answer (score 1):

google maps is always shown in the projection SRID EPSG:900913. You will need to make sure your other layers are being added to your application using the same projection or being converted on the fly.